# Best way to represent data as features vectors in Python

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, pandas

I have a list of events topic retrieved from a tweets collection.
A set of features have been extracted and their values normalized between 0 and 1. An example of an event:

```
"paris_attack_news-20150107_100842-20150107_112852": {
    "ages": 0.5557594006583049,
    "density": 0.0012022814250710345,
    "followers": 0.1144661871115895,
    "friends": 0.13507755010659472,
    "hashtagCount": 0.033270950301517985,
    "lifespan": 0.29613227044582224,
    "mediaCount": 0.1095890410958904,
    "mentionCount": 0.020275919732441472,
    "objectivity": 0.2850584551023736,
    "polarity": 0.2963684492294102,
    "retweetCount": 0.21431767337807606,
    "status_count": 0.09222093073720204,
    "truth": 1.0,
    "tweetCount": 0.01300578034682081,
    "urlCount": 0.29494007989347537,
    "verified": 0.3392857142857143
}
```

Now I need to represent each event as an array of its features:

```
paris_attack_news-20150107_100842-20150107_112852 = [0.5557594006583049, 0.5557594006583049, 0.1144661871115895, 0.13507755010659472, ...]
```

After that, I need to manipulate/aggregate the array values in some ways to get a specific events sorting based on the results.

The data are already in a Python Pandas DataFrame (event name as index, features as columns).

Which is the best way (data structure for further storing or libraries such as NumPy, sklearn or similar) to build the arrays starting from this?

P.S.: Then I'll need to apply some machine learning alghoritms to detect if an event is TRUE or FALSE, using the feature named "truth": 1 or 0 as label classification.

Comment: You already have Pandas DataFrame, it is the best way I know to have a table of features + label. Pandas provides you with many tools to deal with missing values, aggregate, generate new features, and it is easy to use a DataFrame with all available machine learning modules like sklearn. Example: https://medium.com/simple-ai/pandas-library-in-a-nutshell-intro-to-machine-learning-3-acbd39ec5c9c

Comment: Seems like you are usinga JSON

Answer (score 1):

Numpy is best.  You can just take

np.array(dict.values()).

Eg,  dict = Paris_attck

Most ML libraries operate on numpy arrays.

Comment: Better use is for sparse matrices

Comment: Dictionaries are better for sparse matrices.

Comment: Stacking sparse matrices using csr_matrix

Answer (score 1):

Lists in Python are extremely powerful and working with a list of lists is not a complicated procedure.

Something like the following may be something you'd like to investigate.

`events = [] 
for event in range(0,len(df.index)):
   an_event = []
   an_event.append(df[event,'ages'])
   an_event.append(df[event,'density'])
   events.append(an_event)`